# Insect combinatorics challenge

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, homework, combinatorics

Below is the problem taken from Berkeley's Cs61A page [here](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/fa14/lab/lab03/#q9)

> ## Question 9: Insect Combinatorics*
>
> Consider an insect in an M by N grid. The insect starts at the bottom left corner, (0, 0), and wants to end up at the top right corner, (M-1, N-1). The insect is only capable of moving right or up. Write a function paths that takes a grid length and width and returns the number of different paths the insect can take from the start to the goal. (There is a closed-form solution to this problem, but try to answer it procedurally using recursion.)
>   [image]
>
> For example, the 2 by 2 grid has a total of two ways for the insect to move from the start to the goal. For the 3 by 3 grid, the insect has 6 diferent paths (only 3 are shown above).
>
> ```
> def paths(m, n):
>     """Return the number of paths from one corner of an
>     M by N grid to the opposite corner.
>
>     >>> paths(2, 2)
>     2
>     >>> paths(5, 7)
>     210
>     >>> paths(117, 1)
>     1
>     >>> paths(1, 157)
>     1
>     """
>     "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
> ```

This solution is with the knowledge of 'higher order function' and 'recursion'. I've yet to learn data structures and algorithms (if required).

Idea: Started from the destination and found the possibilities. As per the skill level, the solution took 3 hours of my time. Please provide feedback on this.

```
def paths(m, n):
    """Return the number of paths from one corner of an
    M by N grid to the opposite corner.

    >>> paths(2, 2)
    2
    >>> paths(5, 7)
    210
    >>> paths(117, 1)
    1
    >>> paths(1, 157)
    1
    """
    count_paths = 0 
    def find_number_of_paths(x, y):
        if x == 0 and y == 0:
            nonlocal count_paths
            count_paths += 1
            return
        if x > 0:
            find_number_of_paths(x-1, y)
        if y > 0:
            find_number_of_paths(x, y-1)
    find_number_of_paths(m-1, n-1)
    return count_paths
```

1. Can we avoid re-assignment operator on `count_paths`?
2. Can we avoid nested function definitions?
3. Is there a name for above solution approach in algorithm world? Any better approach?

**Note:** As per this assignment, no usage of data model is recommended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `nonlocal` rather than `global` is certainly good, but better yet would be returning values.

```
def paths(m, n):
    def find_number_of_paths(x, y):
        if x == 0 and y == 0:
            return 1

        ret = 0

        if x > 0:
            ret += find_number_of_paths(x-1, y)

        if y > 0:
            ret += find_number_of_paths(x, y-1)

        return ret

    return find_number_of_paths(m-1, n-1)
```

That lets us elide the outer function entirely:

```
def paths(x, y):
    if x == 1 and y == 1:
        return 1

    ret = 0

    if x > 1:
        ret += paths(x-1, y)

    if y > 1:
        ret += paths(x, y-1)

    return ret
```

It's a bit strange to critique this since "no closed-form solution" basically means no good solution. There are ways of speeding this up, though, that avoid that. A trivial one is memoization:

```
_paths_cache = {(1, 1): 1}
def paths(x, y):
    if (x, y) in _paths_cache:
        return _paths_cache[x, y]

    ret = 0

    if x > 1:
        ret += paths(x-1, y)

    if y > 1:
        ret += paths(x, y-1)

    _paths_cache[x, y] = ret
    return ret
```

Comment: What is closed-form solution?

Comment: So, ret=0, executes only once?

Comment: \${(x-1) + (y-1)} \choose {y-1}\$

Comment: `ret = 0` executes nearly once per call to `paths`, which is approximately \$xy\$ times.

Comment: The first version is working. This looks complex for me. How did you do that? I mean, placing 'ret=0' in the middle was a tough task. This is the reason I used nonlocal.

Comment: Each call to the function has a different `ret`. Look at each function call in isolation: `find_number_of_paths(4, 3)` is equal to `find_number_of_paths(3, 3) + find_number_of_paths(4, 2)`, so we add each to `ret` and return the answer.

Comment: Consider [these fibonacci functions](https://gist.github.com/Veedrac/91f47e67ea0459564d04). The first is from your lab materials (although I had to fix it). The second uses a `ret` variable. These do the same thing.

Comment: So this is an example of tree recursion?

Comment: @overexchange Yep.